# Regular expressions : Select one or more unique values from a list

Tags: regex

So I have this simple problem .... I need to generate some random test data.

Something like this .... (there are many other columns as well, but I am omitting them for simplicity ....) to generate my dummy data using [this website](https://www.mockaroo.com/) using regular expressions.

```
CourseCode  Trimester
-------------------
A100    T1
A200    T1, T2
A300    T1, T2, T3
B400    T2, T3
```

Possible trimester values are T1,T2,T3. 
A course may fall under any 1, 2 or all 3 trimesters.

I need a regular expression, which can give me any of these results from the following list .... **one result at a time**.

- T1
- T2
- T3
- T1,T2
- T1,T3
- T2,T3
- T1,T2,T3

So far, I have tried this one ...

```
(T1(T2|T3))|(T2(T1|T3))|(T3(T1|T2))
```

But it only gives me

- T1,T2
- T2,T3
- T3,T1

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify if `T1,T1` or `T1,T2,T1` is valid?

Comment: it seems the question is match all the possible unique combinations. it doesnt really look like a job for regex if everything is variable

Comment: @Zephyr Pellerin T1,T1 is not valid. I only want unique values. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you need something like this:

```
(T\d+,)*(T\d+)
```

Basically, zero or more of something like `T1,` followed by something like `T2`

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/8q04YTvrBak1ycy0)

But... if you want to specifically match things in an actual list (especially if this list can change)... you really shouldn't be doing it with just a regex. In that case, the better answer would depend on the language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

difficult to set value constraints with regex.  I'm not sure this can be further simplified

```
(T(1|2|3))|(T1,(T2|T3|T2,T3))|(T2,T3)
```